# what are the different ways to use the variable in many functions within a module?

Tags: 7, forms, sessions

I want to access a variable changed in one function in another. I tried this with Session and global variables. I need the variable to be persisted across multiple page requests. are there any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[variable_set](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7.x)

> sets a persistent variable.
>
> Case-sensitivity of the variable_* functions depends on the database
>   collation used. To avoid problems, always use lower case for
>   persistent variable names.

[variable_get](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7.x)

> Returns a persistent variable.
>
> Case-sensitivity of the variable_* functions depends on the database
>   collation used. To avoid problems, always use lower case for
>   persistent variable names.

[variable_del](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_del/7.x)

> Unsets a persistent variable.
>
> Case-sensitivity of the variable_* functions depends on the database
>   collation used. To avoid problems, always use lower case for
>   persistent variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Use below functions:

1. [variable_set()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7.x) : Sets a persistent variable.
2. [variable_get()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7.x) : Returns a persistent variable.